# Invalid double when I try to convert string to double

Tags: java, android

I am actually trying to convert string data in double. 
I do not understand why I have always the error 'Invalid Double' when I try to do this :

```
double freq[]=new double[nb_points];
double pxx[]=new double[nb_points];
int nb_point=100;

 for (int i=0; i<bytes/2;i=i+15)
 {
    String strReceived_freq = new String(buffer,i, i+15);   
    freq[i]=Double.parseDouble(strReceived_freq);
    freq_value.setText(String.valueOf(freq[i]));
 }
```

Thanks for your help !

Comment: i think use object Double obj[]=new Double[size]

Comment: did you chekced the content of `strReceived_freq` ? what is in it? maybe some wrong format dot vs comma

Comment: ? I did that for freq[] and pxx []

Comment: @Fusselchen ok I'll try this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many cases in which this error can occur.
Example your string is "" (empty) or not properly parsed.

You need to catch the exception here.

Something like this..

```
double freq[]=new double[nb_points];
        double pxx[]=new double[nb_points];
        int nb_point=100;

        for (int i=0; i<bytes/2;i=i+15)
        {
            String strReceived_freq = new String(buffer,i, i+15);
            try {
                freq[i]=Double.parseDouble(strReceived_freq);
            }catch (NumberFormatException e){
                freq[i]=0;
            }

            freq[i]=Double.parseDouble(strReceived_freq);
            freq_value.setText(String.valueOf(freq[i]));
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should check value of String "strReceived_freq" may be it is "".

Minor suggestion instead of Doulbe.parseDoulbe() you should use

Double d = new Double(strReceived_freq);